# How can I move 2 of my commits to a new branch?

Tags: git

my git log is like this:

```
commit 7cfdafdad623d2529f9c2069549619d117f4f43ec
commit afdafdafd0165af0651c1c4670bc2cd53738c2433
commit 1235cebdd758c1314ca0002a2c11f9693f43deafb
...
```

How can I move the most recent 2 commits to a new branch? (Note: most recent are at the top)

I am thinking

```
git branch newbranch
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git checkout newbranch
git commit -a 
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git checkout newbranch
git commit -a
```

Is there a better way?  I think my way will lost the git comments. I kind of remove the commit and re-check in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply issue the following two commands:

```
git branch new_branch_name
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Explanation:

1. Create a branch called `new_branch_name` in the current (latest) commit, but don't checkout that branch.
2. You're still on the `old_branch`. Next step is to point it to `1235ce`. This is done using `reset --hard`.

Now `old_branch` is pointing to `1235ce`, and `new_branch_name` is at `7cfdaf`.